# Difference between "Restart & Run All" and "Run All" in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am curious about the difference in functionality between "Restart and Run all", under Kernel, and "Run all" under 'cell'.

I feel less comfortable with the "restart" aspect and it is more time consuming since Jupyter asks for confirmation.

Is there any practical difference? Any reason to chose one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Restart and Run all" will restart the kernel, that means that you will lose all the variables and computations you have in your memory and after that It'll run all cells. "Run All" will run all cells with all existing variables in memory.
You use "Restart and Run all" can be useful is some cases, for example, when you need to import again a library because you updated. Sometimes, It's  good to be sure that your code can run entirely without problems, because it's possible that you have defined variables in your environment, that You don't need anymore, but affect your program.

Answer (score 2):

Restart pertains mainly to the kernel - restarting it will mean you lose any variables in memory and any imports you've done. In some scenarios, you may not need to restart, or it may be undesirable, for example if you are loading a large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

A notebook kernel is a computational engine that executes the code contained in a notebook. The kernel consumes significant CPU and RAM. I think the difference is that the RAM is not release until the kernel is restarted by 'Restart and run' command under kernel.